# Qt framework: How to make widgets look native?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, osx-yosemite

I have read here(http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) that if you don't set a QStyle, it will stick to the default, which will make the app look native on the system it is running on.

I am currently using OS X(Yosemite) and it doesn't look native at all. All the buttons have corners, despite having a size big enough.

I did not manage to make them look native. Some help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

PS Using Qt 5.4

PPS screenshot:

[image]

Comment: And what's the look you're after? Because if you think that putting two giant pushbuttons will look nice, well...

Comment: But what did you put in there exactly? Can you paste some code? And describe what result you're looking for?

Comment: Qt probably hasn't picked up with the new UI, should get fixed in the next release.

Comment: This is happening on a fresh project?